# How to enable XDebug on phalconphp/ubuntu-16.04 docker image?

Tags: docker, phalcon

I'm using **phalconphp/ubuntu-16.04** docker image and I want to enable XDebug on that image. Quote from image documentation on https://hub.docker.com/r/phalconphp/ubuntu-16.04

> Xdebug is disabled by default. To enable it you'll need pass
> XDEBUG_REMOTE_ENABLE and/or XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST environment variables.
>
> Variable  Description
> XDEBUG_REMOTE_ENABLE=1    This will enable Xdebug.
> XDEBUG_REMOTE_AUTO_START=1    Enable autostart will catch all requests.
> XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST=192.168.0.1    Xdebug remote host.
> XDEBUG_REMOTE_PORT=9000   Will setup remote host. If you want to start
> debug session manually pass variable XDEBUG_SESSION_START via GET,
> POST or COOKIE.
>
> Note: To use this feature you'll need set
> XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST.

This is my run statement

```
docker run -d --network TEST 
-p 80:80 
-p 9000:9000 
-e XDEBUG_REMOTE_ENABLE=1 
-e XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST=host.docker.internal 
-v ${workspaceFolder}:/app 
-v ${workspaceFolder}/docker:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled 
phalconphp/ubuntu-16.04:php-7.2
```

When I look at **phpinfo()**, xdebug is not loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Your docker run statement is fine. There seems to be a bug in the `Dockerfile` of phalcon. I followed the instruction in the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/phalconphp/ubuntu-16.04) and I can verify that this is a bug.

---

**STEPS TO REPRODUCE**

1. Create two files `index.php` and `nginx.conf` in following structure.

[image: screenshot of file structure]

These are the contents of the file

```
<?php
// index.php
phpinfo();
```

```
# nginx.conf
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name example.com;

    index index.php;
    root /app/public;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass             unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index            index.php;

        include                  fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param            SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_read_timeout     300;
        fastcgi_buffer_size      16k;
        fastcgi_buffers          4 16k;
    }
}
```

2. Then use this command to run the docker container

```
docker run \
    -p 80:80 \
    -v $(pwd):/app \
    -v $(pwd)/docker/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:ro \
    -e XDEBUG_REMOTE_ENABLE=1  -e XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST=host.docker.internal \
    phalconphp/ubuntu-16.04:php-7.2
```

**Expected Result**
Xdebug to be enabled

**Actual Result**
Xdebug was not enabled

---

When I dug deeper into the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/phalcon/dockerfiles/blob/master/app/ubuntu-16.04/php-7.2/Dockerfile) I found the there are entryfile scripts but `ENTRYFILE` instruction is missing in the `Dockerfile`. I have created a [Pull Request](https://github.com/phalcon/dockerfiles/pull/33) which will fix this issue.